# How to change properties values via Spring Boot Admin Console?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-boot-admin

I have a Spring boot application with Spring Boot Admin Console:
[image: SBA]

It shows `Details`, `Metrics` etc. Also there a `Environment` tab.

1. Is it possible to change application.properties values via Environment tab?
2. If I add new value to property key and push `Update environment` button nothing change in application. Why? Do i need to do any additional set ups?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

My dependencies from POM:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-docs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaybird</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.protectimus.api.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.moocar</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-gelf</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </dependency>



     <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
       </dependency>-->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Did you click "Refresh context" Button?

Answer (score 2):

I have setup a little test-Environment...

With SBA I have updated an environoment .. a little hello-world REST Endpoint shows the new value ... but inside the SBA is the OLD Value.

Perhaps you need a `@RefreshScope` annotation at your beans ?